# Could not find a kernel image on LiveCD 14.04 LTS

Tags: kernel, 14.04, live-cd, dvd, cd

I downloaded the ISO of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 4 times from 4 different official mirrors and when I use them they all gave me this message, I can not even get to the menu to check the disk.

```
Could not find kernel image: /casper/vmlinuz
```

Message:

[image: Message]

Mirrors:

[image: mirrors]

Burned DVD:

[image: Burned DVD]

Sorry but I can't post images and more than two links because I'm newbie in askubuntu. :(

Comment: Please provide us information on your computer hardware. Have you verified you are using the right version of architecture .ISO for your hardware? That is, are you maybe trying to boot an x86_64 (aka AMD64, or 64-bit) .iso on an x86 (aka i386, or 32-bit) system?

Comment: @0xSheepdog yes, I checked the system architecture coincided with the ISO, i have 32-bits amd processor [AMD E-300 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics (2 CPUs), ~1.3GHz] [4GB RAM][145GB avalible Hard Drive][BIOS: InsydeH2O Version CCB.03.61.11F.43]... a while ago I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS without any problem but now the ISO seems to be corrupted because i tried to mount a VirtualMachine with VirtualBox and i got the same messsage before that i can get into the livecd menu (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Accelerated_Processing_Unit_microprocessors#Ultra-Mobile_Processors) your E-300 APU is AMD64 (x86_64) architecture.

Try downloading the ubuntu-14.04-desktop-AMD64.iso image and use it to install.

Comment: but i had installed 12.04 LTS 32bits without any problem mmm that's weird, 32bit can not run on a 64bit processor? i configured VirtualBox with Ubuntu 32-bits and it boot with the 32bits iso, it should run without any problem but i got the same error... anyway I'll try and I will notify

Comment: I agree with your point, 32-bit should run. But I am not very familiar with the vagaries of AMD processors. With Intel I am fairly certain it would work. You may also want to check the media to be certain it was burned without errors.

Comment: i don-t know the reason but it worked with 64 bits, should have worked just 32 bits, now I realize that it fetches all 3 isos were corrupt, not so the 64bit ![CORRUPTED ISOS](http://i.imgur.com/snnDgMb.png)